# How can we show our user LinkedIn recommendations on our website?

Tags: cakephp-1.3, linkedin-jsapi

We want to extract or get the our website user's recommendations on LinkedIn and show it on our website?

I searched and find to use these fields:

```
(id,first-name,last name,recommendations-received)
```

But can someone describe to me more how to use it like currently we are getting data in form of response from LinkedIn getting:

```
$response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-urls::(original),email-address,public-profile-url,summary,phone-numbers,im-accounts,twitter-accounts,primary-twitter-account,headline)');
```

Should I add to new fields of recommendations to these response field or do something else?

Comment: Is there anything in the LinkedIn APIs ?  https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have?